# Star Citizen Python API Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests

I have worked with a few API's, but not sure how to get started with sending requests for Star Citizen. Does anyone know how you might go about using python to send a get request for say getting some data on game items. Here is their official API documentation but not sure where to start!

https://starcitizen-api.com/gamedata.php#get-items

Could anyone post an example get request that return data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the docs, the urls seems to be `/xxxxxxxx/v1/gamedata/get/3.6.1/ship?name=Avenger` or some such where i guess the xxx is your personal key or account or whatever

try this:

```
import requests
url = '/xxxxxxxx/v1/gamedata/get/3.6.1/ship?name=Avenger'
response = requests.get(url, verify = False)
contents = response.json()
```

just make sure the url is complete, should work the same for any web API really

EDIT:

from the docs it looks like the url should look like this (since the host is listed as `Host: api.starcitizen-api.com`

`https://api.starcitizen-api.com/xxxxxxx/v1/gamedata/get/3.6.1/ship?name=Avenger`

Comment: Thanks vencaslac. That's the direction I was heading as well. When I try this with a valid api key i get invalid url. Should there be a url listed somewhere?

Comment: Thanks vencaslac! The response seems to be fine although it pulls no data but I can work it from here I think! Thanks again :-)

Comment: i don't play SC, so i have no domain knowledge, those values are just what was in the docs, maybe it has to be one of your ships?